# Serializing a RangeDict using YAML or JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, yaml, pickle, jsonpickle

I am using [RangeDict](https://github.com/WKPlus/rangedict) to make a dictionary that contains ranges. When I use Pickle it is easily written to a file and later read.

```
import pickle
from rangedict import RangeDict

rngdct = RangeDict()
rngdct[(1, 9)] = \
    {"Type": "A", "Series": "1"}
rngdct[(10, 19)] = \
    {"Type": "B", "Series": "1"}

with open('rangedict.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(rngdct, f)
```

However, I want to use YAML (or JSON if YAML won't work...) instead of Pickle since most of the people seem to hate that (and I want human readable files so they make sense to people reading them)

Basically, changing the code to call for yaml and opening the file in `'w'` mode, not in `'wb'` does the trick for the writing side, but when I read the file in another script, I get these errors:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 129, in construct_mapping
value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 61, in construct_object
"found unconstructable recursive node", node.start_mark)
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: found unconstructable recursive node
```

I'm lost here. How can I serialize the rangedict object and read it back in it's original form?

Comment: I think the `NSStock` was  a typo, if not please add its definition to your example.

Comment: That's right! Sorry for that, I renamed the variables, but forgot this one. Thanks for the remark! @Anthon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR; Skip to the bottom of this answer for working code

---

I am sure some people hate `pickle`, it certainly can give some headaches when refactoring code (when the classes of pickled objects move to different files). But the bigger problem is that pickle is insecure, just a YAML is in the way that you used it.

It is for interesting to note that you cannot pickle to the more readable [protocol level 0](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) (the default in Python 3 is protocol version 3) as:

pickle.dump(rngdct, f, protocol=0)
will throw:

> TypeError: a class that defines **slots** without defining **getstate** cannot be pickled

This is because the `RangeDict` module/class is a bit minimalistic, which also shows (or rather doesn't) if you try to do:

```
print(rngdict)
```

which will just print `{}`

You probably used the PyYAML `dump()` routine (and its corresponding, unsafe, `load()`). And although that can dump generic Python classes, you have to realise that that was implemented before or roughly at the same time as Python 3.0. (and Python 3 support was implemented later on). And although there is no reason a YAML parser could dump and load the exact information that `pickle` does, it doesn't hook into the `pickle` support routines (although it could) and certainly not into the information for the Python 3 specific pickling protocols.

Any way, without a specific representer (and constructor) for `RangeDict` objects, using YAML doesn't really make any sense: it makes loading potentially unsafe and your YAML include *all of the gory details* that make the object efficient. If you do `yaml.dump()`:

```
!!python/object:rangedict.RangeDict
_root: &id001 !!python/object/new:rangedict.Node
  state: !!python/tuple
  - null
  - color: 0
    left: null
    parent: null
    r: !!python/tuple [1, 9]
    right: !!python/object/new:rangedict.Node
      state: !!python/tuple
      - null
      - color: 1
        left: null
        parent: *id001
        r: !!python/tuple [10, 19]
        right: null
        value: {Series: '1', Type: B}
    value: {Series: '1', Type: A}
```

Where IMO a **readable** representation in YAML would be:

```
!rangedict
[1, 9]:
  Type: A
  Series: '1'
[10, 19]:
  Type: B
  Series: '1'
```

Because of the sequences used as keys, this cannot be loaded by PyYAML without major modifications to the parser. But fortunately, those modifications have been incorporated in [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), so "all" you need to do is subclass `RangeDict` to provide suitable representer and constructor (class) methods:

```
import io
import ruamel.yaml
from rangedict import RangeDict

class MyRangeDict(RangeDict):
    yaml_tag = u'!rangedict'

    def _walk(self, cur):
        # walk tree left -> parent -> right
        if cur.left:
            for x in self._walk(cur.left):
                yield x
        yield cur.r
        if cur.right:
            for x in self._walk(cur.right):
                yield x

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        d = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
        for x in node._walk(node._root):
            d[ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedKeySeq(x)] = node[x[0]]
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, d)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        d = cls()
        for x, y in node.value:
            x = constructor.construct_object(x, deep=True)
            y = constructor.construct_object(y, deep=True)
            d[x] = y
        return d


rngdct = MyRangeDict()
rngdct[(1, 9)] = \
    {"Type": "A", "Series": "1"}
rngdct[(10, 19)] = \
    {"Type": "B", "Series": "1"}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.register_class(MyRangeDict)  # tell the yaml instance about this class

buf = io.StringIO()

yaml.dump(rngdct, buf)
data = yaml.load(buf.getvalue())

# test for round-trip equivalence:
for x in data._walk(data._root):
    for y in range(x[0], x[1]+1):
        assert data[y]['Type'] == rngdct[y]['Type']
        assert data[y]['Series'] == rngdct[y]['Series']
```

The `buf.getvalue()` is exactly the readable representation shown before.

If you have to deal with dumping `RangeDict` itself (i.e. cannot subclass because you use some library that has `RangeDict` hardcoded), then you can add the attribute and methods of `MyRangeDict` directly to `RangeDict` by grafting/monkeypatching.

Comment: This is indeed a working answer. Your YAML library does the trick flawlessly and also yields a nicely human readable output file. The "round trip equivalence" part is a bit shady to me, but it does not fall into assert exceptions, so I guess my RangeDict has the correct format / data?

Comment: That equivalence part relies on some internals, it just test all the ranges and makes sure that the `rngdct` that was created has the same value for the first value in that range (`x[0]`), as the `data`. Just to make sure you don't `load()` something and got rid of the error, but end up with something entirely different from what you start out with.